# label gridlines in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to label my vertical gridlines in a plot. I have set my xticks and also enabled my vertical grids.

```
ax.set_xticks([0,10,12,17])
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
```

Now my question is:
Is it possible to label the gridlines? For example the gridline vertical from the x value 10 should be labeled 'number 10'. Also the labels should be rotated by 90°.

I tried it with `pl.text()` but that can't be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ax is `matplotlib.axes.Axes` .

I think what you need is - `Axes.set_xticklabels()` function. Documentation for that is [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels).

Example -

```
ax.set_xticklabels(labels) #labels is a list of strings,that should be the labels for your xticks.
```

Comment: i already have labels on the xaxis. In my special case on the x-axis are kilometers. Now i want to keep the kilometers as well as the name of the position at this kilometer for example:

Comment: at km 10 i want a vertical label this is km 10.

Comment: You want two labels in the x-axis?

Comment: yes. the labels from the xaxis should contain the numbers and above, on the grid, should be something like an explanation of the numbers.

Comment: Would it be possible to visualize what you want? Maybe an image or so?

Comment: Upload it to some image site and paste its URL here ?

Comment: http://snag.gy/mE1al.jpg     the density of the grids is very high in that plot i will split that plot later in 4 parts. for now i just wanna know how i can add the 'element' in my picture for every vertical grid. first grid element 1 and so on

Comment: Sounds like you want to add an `ax.text` label in the plot.